# Property files for Java EE application on Geronimo

Tags: jakarta-ee

What is the standard/best practice for reading external property files for a Java EE app in Geronimo?

Answer (score 1):

This is explained here

http://cwiki.apache.org/GMOxDOC21/locating-your-application-specific-configuration-files.html

and here (for IBM WASCE, which is basically same as G)

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=2359&context=SS6JMN&dc=DB560&dc=DB520&uid
=swg21266061&loc=en_US&cs=UTF-8&lang=en&rss=ct2359websphere

You could also implement it using SharedLib GBean.

```
<sys:gbean name="MyProps"class="org.apache.geronimo.system.sharedlib.SharedLib">
    <attribute name="classesDirs">var/MyPropsDirectory</attribute>
    <!-- the directory %Geronimo_Install%/var would be my best choice to place
     such files  and I belive is the best practice way to do this-->
    <reference name="ServerInfo">
        <name>ServerInfo</name>
    </reference>
</sys:gbean>
```

Cited from [here](http://marc.info/?l=geronimo-user&m=123547929503510&w=2)